# dynamic connection string for injected repository

Tags: entity-framework, dependency-injection, structuremap, multi-tenant

I'm building a multi tenant (db per tenant) application.

- the application - .net MVC4
- the data layer entity framework code first repositories
- the repositories are injected into the application via structure map

The structuremap config:

```
var connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["AccessControlDB"].ToString();

ObjectFactory.Initialize(x =>
    {
        x.For<IAccessControlContext>().Use<AccessControlContext>().Ctor<string>("connectionString").Is(connectionString);
        x.For<IGenericRepository<Identities>>().Use<GenericRepository<IAccessControlContext, Identities>>();
        x.Scan(scan =>
        {
            scan.AssembliesFromApplicationBaseDirectory();
            scan.ExcludeNamespace("StructureMap");
            scan.WithDefaultConventions();
        });
    });
```

A new requirement for having each tenant isolated by database has come up, so having tenantIDs is no longer sufficient.

**I've gotten as far as having a meta database to store the data required to construct the connection strings, but I'm at a loss on how to pass the connection string to the repository.**

At first, I thought I could just expose the connection string as a property, but there is no way to change the connection string after the context has already been instantiated by structuremap.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of passing a connection string to the repositories, do the following:

1. Inject an `IContextFactory` into the repositories. This context factory can create new `DbContext` instances.
2. Inject an `ITenantProvider` into the connection factory.

Injecting a context factory into the repositories has the following advantages:

1. Make it considerably easier to configure the container, because you remove the ambiguity that `string` values bring and this prevents you from having to inject that connection string into many classes.
2. It allows you to hide the complexity of resolving the connection string behind an abstraction, since the context factory is now responsible of creating the right connection string (based on the tenant information it got from the `ITenantProvider` implementation).
3. By returning new `DbContext` instances from the factory instead of returning connection strings, you hide the creation of the `DbContext`. This makes your repository easier and makes it easier to change it later on.

Note that I'm just guessing here how your repository works so the use of an `IContextFactory` might not be the best option. But by preventing to inject the connection string directly and hiding it behind an abstraction (that even does a bit more than just returning that connection string), you can make both your DI configuration and application code considerably easier and maintain and test.

Comment: How would the ITenantProvider know which tenant is requesting data?

Comment: How do you currently determine for which tenant the request is?

Comment: the tenants are all in one big db, and every table has a tenant_id column. That way, there isn't a need to know ahead of time what the tenant is. With a tenant/db though, i need to look up the tenant from the meta db, construct the connection string, and then pass it in to the repository. It sounds like the only option is delay the context creation until I need to use the repository, instead of having it created by the constructor?

Comment: My point is, that you are the only one who knows how to select the proper tenant, but I expect it to be information in a cookie, or url. That behavior should be placed in the ITenantProvider.

Comment: But that doesn't mean the creation of thr Context should be delayed, since you can do something like this: `Register<DbContext>(() => contextFactory.CreateContext ())`. This way you can still inject the context into consumers instead of the factory.

Comment: I'm missing something here, the DI container doesn't know which tenant the application is serving when it creates the context, right? In a single database scenario, the DI container doesn't need to know. In a tenant/db scenario, it needs to know before it can construct the context, right?

Comment: The container doesn't have to know: your ITenantProvider implementation is the one to know which tenant the application is verving.

Comment: Hey Steven, Thanks for the brilliant solution. I was about to go down the path of injecting a connection string into my dbContext. Having a contextFactory & tenantProvider is a much better solution. My only confusion still is how would the tenantProvider determine the logged in tenant (Im using Forms Auth in MVC4). I would think the tenantProvider would get this from the Session? Is that the right approach?

Comment: @Yash: You would typically store the tenant Id in either the session or a cookie directly after the user logged in.

Comment: Yes i figured that.. just that it seems wrong to access the session data from a data layer (dataContext or repository).... But i guess thats the only way to go about it... Thanks..

Comment: @Yash: Define your `ITenentProvider` abstraction in the DAL, but define an implementation (for instance `AspNetTenentProvider`) inside your MVC layer. That solves the problem elegantly. Your DAL should not have any notion of the used presentation technology.

Comment: I'm hitting this same issue now and I think this is exactly what I'm looking for, but I just can't understand exactly how this works. Does the ITenentProvider somehow store the connection variables until the DAL needs it? If you called AspNetTenentProvider.setTenent() what happens then? The next line would be DALClientProvider.getClient(clientId), so how does the DAL still know which tenant is being used? 

I feel like I'm missing one single key piece of the puzzle.

Comment: @coryvb123 the ITenantProvider inplementation can store this information in the ASP.NET session for instance, after querying the tenant db.

Comment: @steven Thanks for responding. What does the DAL use to retrieve the tenant info? Correct me if I'm wrong, but it can only see objects at the DAL level and below, so unless you pass something along to each DAL method it doesn't know to look in the session or somewhere else. Is that correct? How do I set that once at the presentation layer so that the DAL/DbContext will know which tenant we're dealing with? I don't have a contextFactory, is that a key element to making this work? Even then, how does a contextFactory at the use ITenantProvider to look at the Session?

Comment: @coryvb123 the answer to your question is already given here in the comments.