# Is it possible to pass a value from session into UnitOfWork constructor using dependency injection?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, dependency-injection, ninject, parameter-passing, unit-of-work

I am currently working towards supporting multi-tenancy in an mvc4 project. Right now, I understand that I have to execute the following query in the UnitOfWork constructor:

```
"USE FEDERATION <FederationName>(FederationKey=<FederationID>) WITH RESET, FILTERING=ON"
```

Now the values (FederationName) and (FederationID) are retrieved from the session, so I would have to pass these as parameters to the UnitOfWork constructor, but I'd like to know, is this possible using dependency injection? If yes, how? I'm using ninject as dependency injector.
This is how the bindings are currently done in NinjectWebCommon.cs:

```
private static void RegisterServices(IKernel kernel)
{
    ...
    kernel.Bind<IUnitOfWork>().To<UnitOfWork>();
    ...
}
```

And this is how the UnitOfWork constructor should look like:

```
public UnitOfWork(DbContext dbContext, string federationName, int federationID)
{
    Database = dbContext;
    ((IObjectContextAdapter)dbContext).ObjectContext.Connection.Open();
    Database.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(
        string.Format(@"USE FEDERATION {0}({1}={2}) WITH RESET, FILTERING={3}", 
        federationName,
        "FID",
        federationID,
        "ON"));
}
```

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16843592/dynamic-connection-string-for-injected-repository

Comment: Don't make any calls to the database from within the UnitOfWork constructor. [Constructors should be simple (and fast)](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/03/03/InjectionConstructorsshouldbesimple/).

Answer (score 0):

You could use the method `WithConstructorArgument` when binding the `IUnitOfWork` interface. That way you can bind the parameters to lambdas that will be executed when the IUnitOfWork is resolved, retrieving the federationName\federationID from the session. Check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6065464/ninject-passing-in-constructor-values) about how to use that method.

So, in your case you could register IUnitOfWork as:

```
kernel.Bind<IUnitOfWork>()
.To<UnitOfWork>()
.WithConstructorArgument("federationName", 
                          ctx => HttpContext.Current.Session["federationName"])
.WithConstructorArgument("federationID", 
                          ctx => HttpContext.Current.Session["federationID"]);
```

You may want to consider what happens when those values are not found in the session. Another thing to consider could be wrapping the session in your own context object (interesting if you plan to move away from the session in your application at a later stage). However that should get you started.

Hope it helps!